# Is it correct to ask, "WHY LAUGHING?"

Tags: editing

is it correct to ask, WHY LAUGHING

In a scenerio where the antagonist is laughing at the hero... is it right for the hero to ask... why laughing?

I know of "why are you laughing?" but I've heard people ask "why laughing?"... and everytime I do, it sounds somehow to my ears, so I wonder,is it actually correct to ask, "WHY LAUGHING?"

Comment: The author might be better off asking this question in the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

It is not grammatically correct, no. To be grammatically correct, you would use: "Why are you laughing?"

However, if your hero speaks a certain way and it would be natural for him to ask the question like that, then write "why laughing?". It all depends on your story.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like just one of those slang phrases that become popular for a while and then go away again. Maybe it arose as a slurred version of  "Why're you laughing" that gradually was worn down to "Why ya laughing?" and finally  became "Why laughing?".